# скачивание фалов с сервера (Nuxt.js)

Tags: chrome-extension, nuxt.js, download, electron

В локальной сети, работает web-приложение (Nuxt.js) по скачиванию различных архивов размерами до 2 ГБ, проблема заключается в том, что когда пользователь нажимает кнопку "скачать" на странице приложения, то запускается стандартный менеджер загрузок браузера (в моем случае Chrome), и сохраняет все в папку "Загрузки" на ПК. Возможно ли как-то кастомизировать стандартный менеджер загрузок или получить сведения о статусе скачивания на web-странице. В итоге хотелось бы реализовать такой алгоритм. Пользователь вставляет флешку в ПК, на web-странице нажимает кнопку "скачать", на web-странице появляется кастомный progress bar скачивания файла, файл скачивается, пользователь довольный уходит со своей флешкой.

P.S. Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть? (мои мысли: либо писать свое расширение для Chrome, либо обернуть Nuxt.js в electron.js и копаться в его api)